Getting no active service worker when using firebase getToken Functions
I am using react and firebase push notificaitons in my app. I am facing an issue when I clear the storage and refresh the app on the first try I get the error '

initializing Firebase Messaging:  DOMException: Failed to execute 'subscribe' on 'PushManager': Subscription failed - no active Service Worker

I also verified that my service worker is activated or not using
const regs = await navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations();
console.log(" ~ $$$ ~ requestNotificationPermission ~ regs:", regs)

and in the console I got to know that my firebase service worker is activated.
I am so confused about this and didn't find any solution on the internet, Any help will be appreciated.
one thing I would like to add that I am fetching the firebase configurations from my backend server.
Here is my code for reference
Push notifications file to init service worker



import { useCallback, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/client';
import { requestNotificationPermission } from 'app/utils/firebaseUtils';
import { notify } from 'app/utils/notification/notification';
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getMessaging, onMessage } from 'firebase/messaging';
import { firebaseConfigQuery } from 'graphql/app/pushNotificationQueries';

const PushNotifications = () => {
    const { data }  = useQuery(firebaseConfigQuery);

    const intiFirebaseApp = useCallback(async(config) =>{
        if(!config) return;
        const { vapidKey, ...appConfig } = config;
        const app = initializeApp(appConfig);
                    
        const messaging = getMessaging(app);
                    
        const permission = await requestNotificationPermission(messaging, vapidKey);
            
        if(permission === 'granted') {
            onMessage(messaging, payload => {
                const { topic, payload:message } = payload?.data;
                console.log(' ~ $$$ ~ PushNotifications ~ payload:', payload);
                // no need to show the notification when user login and subscribe to notifications
                if(topic === 'subscription') return;
                notify(topic, {body: message});
            });
        }
    },[]);

    const initFirebaseSW = useCallback(async (config) => {
        if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
            try{
                const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register('/firebase-messaging-sw.js', {
                    scope: '/'
                });
                console.log('Service Worker registered with scope:', registration?.scope);
                await navigator.serviceWorker.ready;
                // await registration?.pushManager?.subscribe({
                //     userVisibleOnly:true,
                // });
                intiFirebaseApp(config);
            }catch(err){
                console.error('Service Worker registration failed:', err);
            }
        }
    }, [intiFirebaseApp]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        const firebaseConfig = data?.affectliSettings?.messaging;
        if(firebaseConfig){
            initFirebaseSW(firebaseConfig);
        }
    },[data, initFirebaseSW]);
     
    
    return null;
};

export default PushNotifications;





Requst notifications function and utils to subscribe and unsubscribe from notifications

export  const requestNotificationPermission = async (messaging, vapidKey) => {
    if (!('Notification' in window)) {
        //eslint-disable-next-line
        console.log('This browser does not support notifications.');
        return Promise.resolve();
    }
    
    // Check the current permission status
    let permission = Notification.permission;
    
    // If permission is 'default', request permission
    if (permission === 'default') {
        permission = await Notification.requestPermission();
    }
    
    if (permission === 'granted') {
        const regs = await navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations();
        console.log(" ~ $$$ ~ requestNotificationPermission ~ regs:", regs)
        const currentToken = await getToken(messaging, {vapidKey});
        console.log(' ~ $$$ ~ requestNotificationPermission ~ currentToken:', currentToken);
        if(currentToken){
            //We can send token to server
           const res = await subscribeNotifications(currentToken);
           const status = res?.data?.pushNotificationAddToken;
           if(typeof status === 'boolean'){
            if(status){
                 //eslint-disable-next-line
              console.log('$$$  : push notifications subscribed successfully');
             }else{
             //eslint-disable-next-line
              console.log('$$$  : push notifications already subscribed');
             }
            }
         }
    } else if (permission === 'denied') {
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        console.log(' ~ requestNotificationPermission ~ permission:', permission);
    }
    return permission;
};




